# org.apache.http.client.methods

Tags: android, http

Hi guys:
   There are several methods such as `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` in this package. But the CONNECT method is lost. Do you know why ? I've tried to add my own HTTP CONNECT method following the `HttpGet` method implementation. i.e. new the class HttpConnect which extends the HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase base class. But this does not work. :-( 
   May you please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to implement any connect method. Check out the example provided in official documentation:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    int l;
    byte[] tmp = new byte[2048];
    while ((l = instream.read(tmp)) != -1) {
    }
}
```

Refer to [sources and documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/).

Comment: Ye, You've given me a sample how to execute HttpGet command. But how to execute a HttpConnect command ??? There's no class called HttpConnect in the APIs. Thank you~!

Comment: You don't need any HttpConnect class. The connection logic is implemented inside HttpGet and HttpPost classes and are invisible to you.